# how to use gtag() on nestjs server

Tags: google-api, gtag.js

I am using nestjs.
I want to call `gtag()` when there is a purchase in the service.
I have looked through several documents but couldn't find the exact thing.
`GTM`, as I understand it, is something that runs on the google server instead of the client, which doesn't seem to fit what I need.
I tried using `gtag-ga` , `ga-gtag` using npm, but that didn't work either, throwing errors.

Is there any other good way to do this?

Comment: Have you managed to find a solution for that?